# How to get yearly, monthly data from postgres in golang gin gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

How to get monthly , weekly, daily yearly data from golang gin using gorm with PostgreSQL.
Here is my struct/schema:

```
type Item struct {
    Name                  string  `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Sku                   string  `json:"sku" binding:"required"`
    Upc                   string  `json:"upc" binding:"required"`
    Quantity              float64 `json:"quantity" binding:"required"`
    Unit_cost             float64 `json:"unit_cost" binding:"required"`
    Discount              float64 `default:"0.0" json:"discount"`
    Tax                   int     `default:"0" json:"tax"`
    Sold                  float64 `default:"0.0" json:"sold"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time
}
```

I want to get data for plotting which will be used by the fronted for plotting graphs

Comment: How do you define "monthly data"? All entries of a specific month? Summed up values? Average? ... What did you try so far?

Comment: for example purposes lets use sum of sold of a specific month